# Custom UDAF not working ( Ksql: Confluent)

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I am facing issues while creating custom UDAF in Ksql. Use case is to find "first" and "last" value of a column in a tumbling window. There is no such built in UDAF (https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/syntax-reference.html#aggregate-functions) so I am trying to create custom UDAF.

I performed following steps based on this document https://www.confluent.io/blog/write-user-defined-function-udf-ksql/

i. created UDAF & AggregateFunctionFactory and registered it in FunctionRegistry as follows:

```
addAggregateFunctionFactory(new MyAggFunctionFactory());
```

ii.Build ksql-engine jar and replaced the same in confluent package at following path $CONFLUENT_HOME/share/java/ksql.

iii.Restarted ksql-server

However, it seems that function is not registered. Any suggestions?

Confluent Version: 4.1.0

Note: I tried creating simple UDF .That works well. Issue is with UDAF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue was that I was naming the function as 'First'  which seems to be some keyword. Changed the function name , it worked

Comment: Glad its working! If this was caused by some issue with `First` being a reserved word, I'd suggest raising a Github issue against KSQL to fix this, so that you get a better error message if someone else was to fall fowl of the same thing.